# How to set input field value in server side?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a search engine with the help of `next.js`.
I want to put a value in the input field. I want to do this in work before it is rendered in client side. I want to do this in work before it is rendered in client side. Because here rendering in server side will already be generated.

How can I do this?

I am able to change the value of input field in client side.

But how to do it in server side?

i am new in `next.js` so I don't know about server side rendering.

Comment: Have you tried actually setting an initial `value` on the input field? Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: @juliomalves Now I solved this problem. I am using pre-rendering and `getServerSideProps`

Comment: @Kheersagar patel docs for better understanding: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering